# org.apache.fop.apps.FOPException"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

Tags: java, ant, apache-fop

I'm using apache ant 1.6.5 to create jar files. In only one location fop jar is present. Still I'm getting the error. I'm using weblogic 10.3.2 to access the application.
Can anyone help me on this.
Below is stacktrace -

```
01/21/2014 18:25:43 FATAL  [PdfReportGenerator] {Method=generateReport}.  class "org.apache.fop.apps.FOPException"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package 
java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.apache.fop.apps.FOPException"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.ags.mhlwreports.generator.pdf.PdfReportGenerator.generatePDFReport(PdfReportGenerator.java:316)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two different versions of FOP in your classpath. Make sure, that you have only one version there. Sometimes vendors package FOP in their own packages - so you might not only look for fop-VERSION.jar but for all org.apache.fop.apps.FOPException in all JARs.